# How to get google fit app setting "activity detection" is on?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

My Application uses Google Fit History API.

It's reading `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA`.

I need to get a valid is "activity detect" of GoogleFit app for that.

What would be a good way to do it?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Its a late answer but maybe it can help someone who is stuck. You need to subscribe the DataTypes from google fit for which you want to record. RecordingApi of GoogleFit provide that function . Like below if you want google fit will record steps for your app do as follows:-

```
Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(fitnessClient,DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA).
        setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                if(arg0.isSuccess()){
                    Log.e("Steps Recording","Subcribe");
                }
            }
        });
```

Similiar for other data types like for Calculating walking distance.Do as follows:- For more information see the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record)

```
Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(fitnessClient,DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA).
    setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
            if(arg0.isSuccess()){
                Log.e("Distance Recording","Subcribe");
            }
        }
    });
```